# WebBrowser не загружает скрипты

Tags: c#, wpf

Создал WebBrowser.

```
<Window x:Class="MyWebBrowser.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWebBrowser"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="300" Width="450"
    Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser  Name="browser" ></WebBrowser>
</Grid>
```

Открою страницу так:

```
  browser.Navigate("http://www.wpf-tutorial.com");
```

Но при запуске получаю такую ошибку (несколько раз)

[image: Ошибка скрипта]

А потом не загружается скрипты на WebBrowser (Даже когда нажимаю кнопку 'Yes')

Вот так показывает сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У  `browser` нет такого свойство как `ScriptErrorsSuppressed `

Comment: Почему убрали метку `WPF` ?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138199/wpf-webbrowser-control-how-to-suppress-script-errors

Comment: Там вроде паказано как скрывать ощибку. Использовал коды, сообщение исчезають, но скрипты всеравно не грузится

Comment: Так `www.wpf-tutorial.com` и так кучу ошибок скриптов выдает при загрузке, только Хром это не показывает, нажмите F12 и увидите. Попробуйте другую страницу, попроще, например `www.google.com`

Comment: Не получилось. Попробовал открыт гугл и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ всеравно показывает не корректно

Comment: А лучше не использовать вообще этот контрол. Он использует старый движок IE7, если не ошибаюсь. Ошибка прошлого так сказать. Если хочется что-то поновее, то используйте CEFsharp, у него есть есть и для WPF контрол.